# Can gesture detector determine if a user was already pressing down before dragging onto a widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I created a Flutter gridview of containers and each one uses an onTap detector to change color, but I want to have dragging functionality to change multiple containers at a time without lifting the pointer.

[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h3cd.png)

Here is my container class that uses OnTap:

```
class CalendarBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final child;
  bool selected;
  final function;

  CalendarBox({this.child, required this.selected, this.function});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: function,
      child: Container(
        // color: Colors.blue,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: selected ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.2)),
        // color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(child: Text(child.toString())),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

this is the gridview that builds the containers:

```
Container(
            width: 290,
            height: 600,
            child: GridView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: calendarBoxCount,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                  crossAxisCount: calendarBoxInEachRow,
                  childAspectRatio: (20 / 10),
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CalendarBox(
                    child: index,
                    selected: boxStatus[index],
                    function: () {
                      //pointer detected on box turns box green
                      selectBox(index);
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ),
```